# WCF - Transaction Scope - cannot enlist while sending to queue within

Tags: wcf

I am having a WCF service which is configured for TransactionScopeRequired = true. It performs following actions.

1) Receives message from the transactional queue
2) Open a transaction scope(new transactionScope()) with in the Service Operation
3. Calla Java Webservice
4) Send results to a transactional queue.

While sending message to a transactional queue it is throwing error "Cannot enlist transaction".
Could anyone please guide me on this?

Thanks
Rakesh

Answer (score 0):

The absence of details (e.g. service and client binding configuration) makes providing a specific response/guidance difficult.

In terms of general guidance, you may want to enable WCF Tracing and Message Logging, which will allow you to monitor/review the WCF transactions and hopefully discover additional information about the issue.

The following links provide a good overview:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx